# How do I launch my ASP.NET application from integration test code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium, continuous-integration, selenium-webdriver

I have written a basic suite of Selenium integration tests for an application we are building. They work great. The only issue is that the application needs to be pre-deployed and running before the tests can run.

How do I launch an ASP.NET MVC application from integration test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to launch my app my running MS build and then basically passing it the path to the sign and starting a new IISExpress process to host it:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
   ErrorDialog = false,
   CreateNoWindow = true,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   Arguments = string.Format("/path:\"{0}\" /port:{1}", this.pathToSite, this.portNumber)
};

string path = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["programfiles(x86)"]) ? processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["programfiles(x86)"] : processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["programfiles"]) + "\\IIS Express\\iisexpress.exe";

processStartInfo.FileName = path;

this.iisProcess = new Process
{
  StartInfo = processStartInfo
};

this.iisProcess.Start();
```

Hope this helps the next guy. Otherwise I will just leave this here for my own reference. I wrapped all this in a method called when starting TestFixtureSetup. Of course I run

```
public void Shutdown()
{
 if(this.IisExpressProcess == null)
 {
   return;
 }

 this.IisExpressProcess.Stop();
}
```

on TestFixtureTearDown.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using SSL?

Comment: I don't see a Stop() method.  Close() doesn't stop IIS Express and Kill throws a InvalidOperationException